# Gaussian and log-concave probability distributions on the integer lattice

Tags: probability, inequality, convex-analysis

I am interested in concentration inequalities for 
probability distributions of the form
$$
p[k] = Z^{-1} F[k] e^{-k^2/\sigma^2}
$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is an integer, $F[k]$ is a log-concave function, and $Z$ is a normalizing constant making $p$ into a probability distribution.  My question is about the moments of such distributions, for example the second moment:

> Does the inequality $$\mathbb{E}|X - \mathbb{E}X|^2 \leq \sigma^2$$ hold if one takes $X$ sampled according to the distribution above?

I am led to ask this question based on the following two results.

**Gaussian distributions on the lattice**

One can use the Poisson summation formula to show that 
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} e^{-(k-t)^2/\sigma^2} \leq 
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-k^2/\sigma^2}
$$
for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  This implies that
$$
\frac{\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{\lambda k} e^{-k^2/\sigma^2}}{\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-k^2/\sigma^2}} \leq \frac{\int e^{\lambda x} e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}\,dx}{\int e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}\,dx}.
$$
That is, the moment generating function for probability distributions of the form
$$
p[k] = Z^{-1} e^{-k^2/\sigma^2}
$$
is bounded by the moment generating function of the corresponding Gaussian distribution.

**Gaussian distributions multiplied by log-concave functions**

Another fact I know about concerns continuous probability distributions of the form
$$
p(x) = Z^{-1} F(x) e^{-x^2/\sigma^2},
$$ 
where $F$ is a log-concave function.  For such distributions we have the moment bounds
$$
\mathbb{E}|X - \mathbb{E}X|^r \leq \mathbb{E} |Y|^r,
$$
where $X$ is sampled according to the above distribution, the random variable $Y$ is Gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$, and $r\geq 1$.  From what I can tell, this inequality is due to Brascamp and Lieb.

**Final remarks**

The reason I'm stuck is that the proofs of the two results above seem incompatible with each other.  That is, if I first try to discretize the Gaussian to the integer lattice, then I am not sure that the argument of Brascamp and Lieb applies anymore.  But if I first multiply by the log-concave function $F(x)$, then I cannot use anything like the Poisson summation formula, as I know nothing about the Fourier transform of $F$.

Ultimately I am interested in higher-dimensional generalizations of this question, but it seems that one dimension is plenty interesting already.